# Add power over Ethernet without new switches?

Tags: networking, power-over-ethernet

I need to power 16 IP phones over their Ethernet connections. I am in the process of changing our switches and only the phones need PoE, everything else is powered by mains cables.

I have contacted the supplier of the phones and for 16 mains leads it will be close to £300. I know it's possible to get a PoE injector that goes between the mains and the phone but I would like to do this as tidily as possible and ideally in bulk.

I imagine something that looks like a switch but doesn't actually 'switch' if that makes sense. Basically I want to inject power to 16 devices at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get multiport PoE injectors, e.g. this one:

http://www.midspans.com/pages/15w/POE370U_15.4W_8-16-24-port_midspan.php

(no idea if it's good or bad, first one I found with 16 ports).

Comment: Is that the name of these things 'midspans'?

Comment: I found that one googling for: multiport PoE injector

Comment: Ha I've been googling for about an hour and didn't come across that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend a low-cost PoE switch or possibly purchasing a higher-end PoE switch/blade along with your switch refresh. The phones will be on their own network/vlan, correct? It may make sense to segregate them and provide a dedicated device (24 or 48 ports).

Comment: The phones are currently on the main (read: only) network. I want to upgrade the switches to support VLANS but a PoE layer 3 switch is expensive. I was thinking a midspan would allow me to upgrade the switches in years to come without worrying about PoE switch capabilities.

Comment: These days, if you're looking at higher-end switches, they'll often have a PoE option. If you're looking at chassis switches, that's definitely the case... But even with 1U rackmount switches, there's less of a penalty in adding PoE functionality. In my case, when I've *just* needed power, I'd buy a low-end PoE switch (e.g. Cisco SRW224G4P-K9-NA).

Comment: My last place of employment made a great deal of use out of the PowerConnect managed POE switches from Dell. They worked well for our environment and the cost difference was under $200 / switch (as compared to managed without POE) at the time. Considering the scalability it was right move.